# how can i change property in EDGE browser

Tags: css, browser, microsoft-edge

i have an `<li>` an with `::before` that contain some css for list. When i test this ul in Edge, the blue discs are not well positioned (top: .5rem) compared to chrome or firefox, and i noticed that it comes from the space that Edge puts on the Lorem text, but i don't know how to remove it o just make a condition on ms Edge to change the "top" proprety
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opo0R.png)

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul>li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-left: 2.2rem;
}

ul>li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: .5rem;
  left: 0;
  width: .9rem;
  height: .9rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #0046fe;
}
```

```html
<ul class="has-text-color has-secondary-color">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam labore nihil quidem voluptate nesciunt non cum magnam sed qui incidunt?</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa temporibus neque voluptas veritatis, rem nemo, ut labore, impedit rerum eius minima. Facere beatae aperiam illum? Quo ea nostrum repellendus mollitia?</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ceque voluptas veritatis, rem nemo, ut labore, impedit rerum eius minima. Facere beatae aperiam illum? Quo ea nostrum repellendus mollitia?</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test your code example with the MS Edge Version 83.0.478.54 (Official Build) (64-bit).

This is the result I get when I test the code.

[image]

UL bullets look properly.

I suggest trying to make a test on the actual MS Edge browser. It may help you to get the proper result.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, am using Microsoft Edge 83, it's on BrowserStack because i am on Linux. and i already tried this code that i found on the internet, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: please see the screenshot in my post